# Use NumPy cleverly to speed up this loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, vectorization

This is quite a theoretical question. It is about the for loop at the end of the code attached.

I have three compatible arrays, Z, Wt_1 and Wt_2.

I used the vectorized columns to speed up the loop, ie I code with columns as though they were scalars, and the whole process works.
But this loop still takes forever (2min+). Here, N = 5000 and a column is 100000 long.

Is there a syntax that speeds this up ?

```
M=100000

N=5000
t0=0.132
T=0.22
dt=T / N

Z0=8
Y0=7

ssqZ=0.04
ssqY=0.01
sigma_Z=np.sqrt(ssqZ)
sigma_Y=np.sqrt(ssqY)
rho=- 0.4

print("Genreating the Brownian Motions...")
Wt_1=rd.randn(M//2,N)
# shape is (50 000,5 000)
Wt_1=np.vstack((Wt_1,-Wt_1))
#print(np.shape(Wt_1))
Wt_2=rd.randn(M//2,N)
Wt_2=np.vstack((Wt_2,-Wt_2))
print("BM generated!\n")

Z=np.zeros((M,N+1))
# shape is (100 000, 5 001)
Y=np.zeros((M,N+1))
#in SciPy indexing starts from 0 :
Z[:,0]=Z0
Y[:,0]=Y0

for i in range(1,N+1) :
    Z[:,i]=Z[:,i-1] - 0.5*(sigma_Z**2)*dt + sigma_Z*np.sqrt(dt)*Wt_1[:,i-1]

    Y[:,i]=Y[:,i-1] + sigma_Y*np.sqrt(dt)* (rho*Wt_1[:,i-1] + np.sqrt(1 - rho**2)*Wt_2[:,i-1])
```

I should add that the same routine in Matlab takes 19s, whereas this Python one takes 137s, which is counter intuitive to me

Comment: Can you give some sample data please ?

Comment: Stochastic processus, brownian-motion-related, is that right @JordiLecoh?

Comment: @Basj yes indeed ! this is basically a simulation of paths of securities

Comment: @Guillaume I can pm you the code

Comment: @JordiLecoch Please post *in the question* some minimal code before to show how to initialize Z, W, so that we can run code ourselves. It's important that questions are *reproducible* on StackOverflow. Like it is currently, we can't even do tests with your code.

Comment: MATLAB does some `jit` compiling that lets it handle loops faster.  Python/numpy does not have that (though tools like `numba` can help).

Comment: Your array access pattern is wrong. In Numpy by default the last axis changes fastest (C-order) in Matlab (Fortran order) its by default the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is quite hard to efficiently vectorize Numpy. In your version you have a vectorized command, which iterates over values which are not contiguously stored in memory [Numpy/C row-major, Fortran/Matlab/Julia is column major.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)

If you want to use Numpy probably the easiest way is to transpose all arrays and operations or use Fortran-ordered arrays (should give a factor of 4).

Another way is to write out the loops and make use of [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) Numba or [Cython](https://cython.org/).

**Numba Example**

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True,cache=True)
def Numba(Z0,Y0,sigma_Y,sigma_Z,Wt_1,Wt_2,rho,dt):
    N,M=Wt_1.shape

    Z=np.empty((M,N+1))
    Y=np.empty((M,N+1))
    Z[:,0]=Z0
    Y[:,0]=Y0
    #the possibillity of negative values can lead to a slow wrap-around check
    for i in nb.prange(M):
        #only beneficial for very large 
        for j in range(N):
            Z[i,j+1]=Z[i,j] - 0.5*(sigma_Z**2)*dt + sigma_Z*np.sqrt(dt)*Wt_1[i,j]
            Y[i,j+1]=Y[i,j] + sigma_Y*np.sqrt(dt)* (rho*Wt_1[i,j] + np.sqrt(1 - rho**2)*Wt_2[i,j])
    return Z,Y
```

**Your Numpy example**

It would also be good to add an example how you got your timings, since generating the Inputs takes more time than the actual computation (at least for the Numba version).

```
def Numpy_not_aligned(Z0,Y0,sigma_Y,sigma_Z,Wt_1,Wt_2,rho,dt):
    Z=np.zeros((M,N+1))
    # shape is (100 000, 5 001)
    Y=np.zeros((M,N+1))
    #in SciPy indexing starts from 0 :
    Z[:,0]=Z0
    Y[:,0]=Y0

    for i in range(1,N+1) :
        Z[:,i]=Z[:,i-1] - 0.5*(sigma_Z**2)*dt + sigma_Z*np.sqrt(dt)*Wt_1[:,i-1]
        Y[:,i]=Y[:,i-1] + sigma_Y*np.sqrt(dt)* (rho*Wt_1[:,i-1] + np.sqrt(1 - rho**2)*Wt_2[:,i-1])
    return Y,Z
```

**Timings**

```
# M=M=50000
%timeit Numpy_not_aligned(Z0,Y0,sigma_Y,sigma_Z,Wt_1,Wt_2,rho,dt)
#25.9 s ± 82.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)    
%timeit Numba(Z0,Y0,sigma_Y,sigma_Z,Wt_1,Wt_2,rho,dt)
#1.03 s ± 127 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: "If you want to use Numpy probably the easiest way is to transpose all arrays and operations or use Fortran-ordered arrays (should give a factor of 4)." ==> Very smart

Answer (score 0):

I tried to move computation out of the loop. It seems that the bottom expression is a simple matrix substraction so I took it out entirely.

```
sqrt_dt = np.sqrt(dt)
A = 0.5*(sigma_Z**2)*dt
B = sigma_Z* sqrt_dt
C = sigma_Y * sqrt_dt * (rho*Wt_1 + np.sqrt(1 - rho**2)*Wt_2)

Y[:,1:N+1] = Y[:,0:N] - C[:,0:N]

for i in range(1,N+1) :
    Z[:,i]=Z[:,i-1] - A + B  * Wt_1[:,i-1]
```

Hopefully, this helps !

Comment: Er, thanks ! But this actually added 2s to the execution time...

Comment: I removed the copy. That should help

Comment: Try again. It went from 88sec to 55sec. That's the best I can do here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to move some repeated computations out of the loop

```
sub_1 = 0.5*(sigma_Z**2)*dt
sub_2 = sigma_Z*np.sqrt(dt)
sub_3 = np.sqrt(1 - rho**2)
sub_4 = sigma_Y*np.sqrt(dt)

for i in range(1,N+1) :
    Z[:,i]=np.add(np.subtract(Z[:,i-1] ,sub_1), np.multiply(Wt_1[:,i-1], sub_2))

    Y[:,i]=np.add(Y[:,i-1] , np.multiply(np.add(np.multiply(Wt_2[:,i-1],sub_3),np.multiply(Wt_1[:,i-1],rho)), sub_4))
```

Comment: This didn't change the execution time at all. I was thinking maybe, there is a way to eliminate the for loop completely ?

Comment: I fear that's not possible as i's value actually depends on i-1's value. We have to compute it sequentially

Answer (score 0):

You won't get any real speed improvements unless the loop is eliminated. Naturally, if we take a closer look, we can formulate the two equations in a different way. I'll demonstrate in brief with the first one, Z:

```
Z(i) = Z(i-1) - C + D*Wt_1(i-1), where C and D are constants.
Z(1) = Z(0) - C + D*Wt_1(0)
Z(2) = Z(1) - C + D*Wt_1(1) = Z(0) - 2*C + D*(Wt_1(0)+Wt_1(1))
i.e. Z(i) = Z(0) -i*C + D*Sum(Wt_1(0..i-1))
```

As you can see, the term Z(0) is actually a constant and is present in all columns; we can simply set it during initialization. The only actual recurrence is in Wt_1. In the Y equation, similarly, the recurrence is dependent on Wt_1 and Wt_2.

And we have our loophole here: this repetition of the Ws is effectively a column-wise growing or cumulative sum, allowing us to discard the for loop and use `np.cumsum` instead. We can also broadcast and add in the constant C in Z's equation by multiplying it with `np.arange(N+1)`.

```
Z = np.ones((M,N+1))*Z0
Y = np.ones((M,N+1))*Y0
W1 = np.cumsum(Wt_1,axis=1)
W2 = np.cumsum(Wt_2,axis=1)

# Calculate Z
Z -= (0.5*(sigma_Z**2)*dt)*np.arange(N+1)
Z[:,1:] = Z[:,1:] + W1*sigma_Z*np.sqrt(dt)

# Calculate Y
Y[:,1:] = Y[:,1:] + sigma_Y*np.sqrt(dt)*(rho*W1 + np.sqrt(1 - rho**2)*W2)
```